# nbconvert latex organization - merging with other latex

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook

What is the best approach to merging latex generated from nbconvert with other latex? In my case I have several company specified forms (which I have latex for) that I want to merge with the notebook/nbconvert generated latex. And, I want to follow the company template for headers/footers/page numbering/table of contents, etc. (these are already available in a latex project).

So with my very basic understanding, I see two possible approaches. Are either viable or is there something else that I am missing?

1) ipython notebook centric - is there a way to modify the preamble to include all the packages and other stuff that my forms need? Company header/footer? etc

or

2) including ipython nbconvert output as part of an external latex project with an include. Is there a way to break out the preamble stuff that nbconvert generates?

I don't have a good handle on how nbconvert pulls together the pieces. So, any adivce or information on how nbconvert deals with latex would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Both 1) and 2) are possible. You can generate the most basic latex with nbconvert using the [base template](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/nbconvert/templates/latex/base.tplx#L115) `--template=base` and insert that into your own company latex. You can even override existing blocks (cf Jinja Documentation) to extend and/or replace existing blocks. Cf this [Old and not up to date explanation](http://carreau.github.io/posts/06-NBconvert-Doc-Draft.html)

Comment: Thank you Matt! In regard to the details - running ipython nbconvert with --template=base (presumably applicable to Option 2) still generates a preamble with /documentclass, usepackage commands and /begin{document}. Is there a way to better organize the integration of what the ipython content needs along side my external content?

Comment: I'm afraid nbconvert is too young for that, we thought of the possibilities so we splitted the files and provide a 'base' template, but only feedback from people like you using it, could help us to narrow down what is needed and what fails.

Comment: Ok. So, the base template is in early development. For our specific use case, the ideal would be for the "basic" to produce two files: 1) with the preamble stuff to be "input" into the larger project's preamble. and 2) the document body to be "input" to the larger project's body. What is the difference currently between the basic and the normal latex generation? The .tex file is about half the size in my case; but, I am not clear what is left out of the basic.